# how to customize Html Helper to act according to the question Type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I made a survey application like the following design:

```
Survey: ID,Name.
Question: ID,SurveyId,QuestionText,QuestionTypeId.

QuerstionType can be (Text, CheckBox, DropDown,RadioButton).
```

What's the best practice to give each question a suitable Html Helper at run time.

currently I am using traditional if else statements.

```
if(QuestionModel.QuestionTypeId==QuestionTypes.Text)
{
   @Html.editor()
}
else if(QuestionModel.QuestionTypeId==QuestionTypes.DropDown)
{
   @Html.DropDownList()
}   
else
{
   ...
}
```

and so on.

I feel that I making something wrong, is there any way to customize one html helper to act differently according to the question Type.

Or if I can attach the html helper to a view model, and use it directly in the view like this:

```
Model.CustomDropdown.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom Html Helper component like this :

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static partial class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {

        public static MvcHtmlString CustomComponent(this HtmlHelper helper, string QuestionTypeId)
        {
            if (QuestionTypeId == "Text")
            {
                var inputTag = new TagBuilder("input");
                inputTag.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputTag.ToString());
            }
            else if (QuestionTypeId == "DropDown")
            {
                var dropDownTag = new TagBuilder("select");
                dropDownTag.MergeAttribute("type", "text");


                var option = new TagBuilder("option");
                option.InnerHtml = "Option 1";
                option.MergeAttribute("value", "option1");

                dropDownTag.InnerHtml += option.ToString();

                option = new TagBuilder("option");
                option.InnerHtml = "Option 2";
                option.MergeAttribute("value", "option2");

                dropDownTag.InnerHtml += option.ToString();

                return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropDownTag.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                var inputTag = new TagBuilder("input");
                inputTag.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputTag.ToString());
            }
        }
     }
}
```

And in your Razor code You can call it like :

```
@Html.CustomComponent("Text")
@Html.CustomComponent("DropDown")
@Html.CustomComponent("Check")
```

In your case while creating the component, You have to pass your Custom Object in parameter instead of string. Also, while calling you will have to pass that custom object. Like :

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomComponent(this HtmlHelper helper, QuestionModel questionModel)
        {
            if (questionModel.QuestionTypeId==QuestionTypes.Text)
            {
                var inputTag = new TagBuilder("input");
                inputTag.MergeAttribute("type", "text");
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputTag.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And in your Razor :

```
@Html.CustomComponent(questionModelObject)
```